# Trigger some event in UC through javascript code

Tags: javascript, user-controls, genexus

It is possible to trigger an event in the UC javascript code?
I have a javascript function in the UC code, and at the end of that function I want to trigger an event that executes the code associated with an event in the Genexus IDE.

Like this:

UC javascript code:

```
function save() {
  ...
  trigger event myevent;
}
```

In Genexus Event tab:

```
Event myevent
  msg("Event triggered!")
EndEvent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the usercontrol definition you can define events with GeneXus Code.

That Event will be fired anytime you want from client side.

[UserControls - Documentation](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?User%20Controls%20-%20Full%20Documentation#Events)  ("Events" section)

Comment: Do you know where is the specification of the language used inside the events?